# SQL UPDATE same sequence number in colB for same set of values in colA

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL UPDATE same sequence number in colB for same set of values in colA

Need either UPDATE SQL statement (preferred) or PL/SQL

```
// Here is script for table create
CREATE TABLE temp 
(   
    "COL_A" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
    "COL_B" NUMBER
);

// script for data load
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('A', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('B', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('C', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('C', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('C', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('D', null);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('D', null);
```

BEFORE

```
-------
TEMP TABLE
-------------
COL_A, COL_B
-------------
A, null
A, null
B, null 
C, null 
D, null
C, null
D, null 
C, null
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
-------------
COL_A, COL_B
-------------
A, 1  
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
D, 4    
C, 3
D, 4    
C, 3
```

For same values in COL_A, we will generate and reuse same sequence number for N number of rows, values for column B are from sequence number temp_seq
I tried several ideas, but I could not reuse same sequence number for same  values (it was generating new one).

Comment: Why is the desired output ordered differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
update temp t
set col_b = (
  select count(distinct col_a)
  from temp u
  where u.col_a <= t.col_a
);
```

Result:

```
 COL_A  COL_B 
 ------ ----- 
 A      1     
 A      1     
 B      2     
 C      3     
 C      3     
 C      3     
 D      4     
 D      4
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EXmMhExA).

Answer (score 1):

`merge` might be another option:

```
SQL> merge into temp a
  2    using (select rowid rid,
  3                  dense_rank() over (order by col_a) col_b
  4           from temp
  5          ) b
  6    on (a.rowid = b.rid)
  7    when matched then update set
  8      a.col_b = b.col_b;

8 rows merged.

SQL> select * from temp;

COL_A           COL_B
---------- ----------
A                   1
A                   1
B                   2
C                   3
C                   3
C                   3
D                   4
D                   4

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```